# Why are my Sims so slow?

Tags: the-sims-3

I have been playing Sims 3 again and it seems that my Sim's actions are too slow for it's own good. I have Late night(+ several others) installed and so my sim is now living in a high-rise(well a 4 floor building with a pool)

Anyway, to get from his pad to the ground floor, it takes him an hour!(in sim time of course). I mean, is it even realistic to take 3 minutes for 5 steps?! Also there are times when he just pauses for a bit but then continues what he's doing(or what he's supposed to do). It does take an extra couple of sim minutes again and that means he has to wake up an hour earlier just to eat a quick meal, pee and shower before running downstairs and wait for the carpool.

Is this a known bug/limitation? Is there a setting fix for it? I am on my early 2010 macbook, with all the lowest settings on.

Comment: Just something to keep in mind: The Sims 3 is a slower game, compared to the Sims 2. If you're more familiar with the latter, that would help account for perceived slowness.

Comment: If you are running in the lowest setting, maybe its your rig that is causing the slow down, note that the timer (Sims time) can go as normal but the animation may lag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from performance issues, there are a few other things that influence the speed of your Sims.

- Sims move slower when they are tired.
- Less active Sims move slower.
- Old Sims move slower than younger Sims.

You can get Sims to run, although I don't think that works with staircases.

The Sims series has never had all actions take a realistic amount of time. If everything was based on real life timing, then Sims would walk so fast it would look silly, or the current 60:1 Sim/RL time ratio would have to be lowered, and then some other actions would seem terribly slow in comparison.

Although The Sims aims to simulate real life (to a degree), sometimes it deviates from realism in order for a "better" playing experience.

As far as I am aware, there is no way to get Sims to move at a speed that is comparable to the speed at which we move in real life.

Comment: "less active" is only relevant in Sims 1 and 2.

Comment: hmm, so does that mean that really going down to the front door will take my sim an hour?

Comment: @corroded - conversely, consider why it only takes a talented Sim a few days to write a master work novel or paint a stunning portrait - instead of weeks, months or years. Don't try to compare the in-game passage of time to real life passage of time, the two are *not* directly comparable. Some things are "slower" than real life, some things are "faster" than real life; it's just how the game is balanced.